# What limitations would a race of human-level IQ tyrannosaurus shaped reptiles with prehensile tails have in building and developing civilization?

Tags: biology, creature-design, warfare, government, technological-development

These reptiles stand about 7-10 feet tall. They have long prehensile tails tapering very thin toward the end. They have large crocodilian mouths, strong legs, and short arms. They are social animals and arrange themselves in packs or bands, not unlike wolves.

They may have discovered fire when proto-humans brought it south into their jungles, but whatever the case, these creatures steadily pushed north destroying proto-human bands until their cold blood prevented them from traveling any farther.

Eventually, proto-humans in the north reclaimed these lands and drove the creatures to extinction or to more southern continents if they developed boats before being driven out.

In their time they hunted megafauna and may have built stone structures to be unearthed in later ages. If not, all that remains of them are the small artefacts of hunter gatherers and their bones.

Natural evolution moves at an accelerated rate in this setting. perhaps 10 to 1 or 100 to 1 compared to earth

In what ways would these creatures differ to humans with respect to the advancement of civilization?

What weapons and structures could these creatures create?

Their tails make for remarkable whips, akin to iguana tail whipping. If piercing implements, flails, or ropes were gripped they could be accelerated to great speeds.

Building the way humans do would be different. Their arms have little function beyond fiddling with objects brought by the tail. The tail is large, but tapered; dexterous at the end, but weak, strong at the base, but without finesse.

Could ranged weapons be used with their body structure?

one potential advantage for humans would be the development of superiors ranged weapons given that these creatures are stronger, faster, and larger than them.

Are these parameters plausible to generate a species that overtakes humans, but is ultimately overcome by them, and if not, which parameter changes would need to be made?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You're asking a lot of different questions at once. We have a strict one question per post policy. Can you [edit] this post down so that it asks one and only one question?

Comment: Perhaps a better framing of your question would be: "given a saurian of this description(describe) with these features able to manipulate its environment (describe). How plausible would  civilization building be for this species?